# Задачи математического моделирования

Tags: моделирование

Необходимы формулировки, условия задач математического моделирования схожие по типу с "**Задачей полёта снаряда**" и "**Задачей всплытия подводной лодки**", желательно с математическими формулами, есть ли хоть какая-та информация по данному предмету, а то в гуглах\яндексах одни задачи *экономического* моделирования?

Зарание благодарю и приношу извинения, если задал вопрос не на том форуме.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например в "Физика для разработчиков компьютерных игр" [здесь.](http://www.kodges.ru/13419-fizika-dlja-razrabotchikov-kompjuternykh-igr.html)

Comment: я бы предложил другую [ссылку][1], а то эта какая то стремная.


  [1]: http://www.knigiebook.ru/Komputer_/GamePrograming/fizika_dlya_razrabotchikov_kompyuternyh_igr.html

Comment: да книгу я нашёл, не стоит об этом волноваться=)

Comment: @shurik, а чем стремная ? В разбираемых примерах не все физические параметры учитываются ? 

Я пролистал, в принципе физика понравилась.

--

А... понял, Вы о ссылке, а не о книге. Книга у меня дома, а ссылку я просто по гуглу спросил и качать ее даже не пробовал.

Comment: Да я про ссылку говорил. хотя  я на экземпляр в pdf другую ссылку не нашел :( Если будет время, выложите где-то. Спасибо!

Comment: на рутрекере прекрасно выложена

Comment: Поиск выдал только 1 результат, формат djvu. Может я не правильно ищу ?

Comment: Я набирал в google - "программирование игр физика C++" (без кавычек).

Comment: а чем вас формат djvu не устраивает?